# Pythonの辞書型をキーワード引数への展開が期待した動作と違う。

Tags: python, python3

Pythonの引数展開について勉強しているのですが、期待した動作と違う理由を教えて下さい。

```
data = ['こんにちは', 'おはよう', 'おやすみ']
keywd = {'sep': ',', 'end': '●'}
print(*data, **keywd) #結果；こんにちは,おはよう,おやすみ●
```

期待した答え

```
#結果；こんにちは おはよう おやすみ , ●
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ドキュメントにもある通り、`sep`は区切りを`end`は最後に表示する文字列を表します。

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
> objects を sep で区切りながらテキストストリーム file に表示し、最後に end を表示します。sep 、 end 、 file 、 flush を与える場合、キーワード引数として与える必要があります。
> [組み込み関数(print)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#print)

期待する出力にするには下記コードにしてください。

```
data = ['こんにちは', 'おはよう', 'おやすみ']
keywd = {'end': ', ●'}
print(*data, **keywd)
# こんにちは おはよう おやすみ, ●
```

Comment: keywdは展開されて`sep=',' end='●'`になってそれが丁度print関数のキーワード引数と同じで中身を書き換えているという事でしょうか？

Comment: そういうことです。指定しない場合はデフォルト引数になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。